# Localhost Inaccessible with WAMP

Tags: php, wamp, windows-10

I am running Windows 10, and I just downloaded WAMP. I am trying to run localhost but whenever I type (http://localhost) into my browser I get this error:

"This site can't be reached. localhost refused to connect. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED."

I have already tested to see if port 8080 is being used, and it is not as it shows this comment:

"Your port 80 is not actually used."

Also, I have tried changing it to port 8888 but it has not worked. The Icon for my WAMP is currently red as well.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have skype open? by default it's set to use port 80 and will prevent WAMPs Apache starting.

Comment: Nope, already checked for that!

Comment: Which WAMP build are you using? PHP7?

Comment: Does it work if you try to access a website directly? For example, if you have a demo website in a folder called `demo` in `wamp/www` (default location), does it work when you go `localhost/demo` ? I have issues with WAMP on Windows 10 as well, but it works when I access a website directly. Not sure what's causing the problem.

Comment: Any errors when you click on wamp then choose turn on and start services?

Comment: @Zanderwar I'm using this one: Apache : 2.4.17 MySQL : 5.7.9 PHP : 5.6.16 PHP : 7, 64 bit

Comment: @Drown I just tried that, still no luck

Comment: @ChinLeung when I do that, there is no response

Comment: I have the same problem, windows 10 64 bit with the PHP7 build however no issue with the PHP5.5.12 build. The differences between versions is dramatic especially regarding performance but if you don't need anything new that PHP7 brings to the table, drop back to 5.5.12

Comment: Awesome, i'll try that!

Answer (score 0):

You may need VC++ 2010 version, i just installed this and it worked :)
(my computer, win10 x64)
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328